# How to move a sprite after the touch from one location to another with a smooth movement with andengine?

Tags: android, coordinates, sprite, andengine

I've a sprite that on touch have to start move along the Y coord.
I need to stop the movement when it reach a default Y coord.
I've tried with setposition() but don't make a smooth movement (like an animation)
How can I do this smooth?

I've try the setvelocity() but I don't know how to stop the movement at a certain coordinates.

```
          @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
                    //TOCCO DELLO SPRITE

                    PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(this);
                    this.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);
                    physicsHandler.setVelocityY(-5f);



                    se.getChild(1).detachChild(this);
                    se.getChild(2).attachChild(this);


                }
```

I also tried the path but I did not understand very well how it works.

**EDIT**

according to Jong I've used the MoveYModifier. It works but on the avd the movement seems jerky. I'll try on a device soon, but is only an avd problem?
I've done this way:

```
   if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){

                    //TOCCO DELLO SPRITE

                    se.getChild(1).detachChild(this);
                    se.getChild(2).attachChild(this);


                    MoveYModifier mod = new MoveYModifier(3, getY(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()- gap);
                    this.registerEntityModifier(mod);


                }
```

**EDIT 2**
tested on a device and works well! very smooth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a`MoveModifier`, read more [here](https://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/modifier/MoveModifier.java?r=ea4ff643a0e58857e92738a6e5449b6a362190cd).

Comment: it works!! thanks a lot! but on the avd the movement seems jerky. i'll try on a device soon, but do yuou know if is only an avd problem?
i've done this way:

`if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){

               //TOCCO DELLO SPRITE
         
               se.getChild(1).detachChild(this);
               se.getChild(2).attachChild(this);
                                
                 
                  MoveYModifier mod = new MoveYModifier(3, getY(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()- gap);
                     this.registerEntityModifier(mod);

 
              }`

Comment: Why are you attaching `this` to the scene? What is `se`? give a bit more details. And the class containing this piece of code is 'Sprite' right?

Comment: you're right, "se" is the scene, and i have this method declared like that:

`sprite = new Sprite(dataV.elementAt(i).x, dataV.elementAt(i).y, tRegionV.elementAt(i))
      
         // gestione del drag & drop
         {
             @Override
             public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
               final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
              
              if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){`
so "this" is the sprite itself. but i've tested on the device and the movemodifier you have recommended, works well!

Comment: I'm not sure you can attach the SAME sprite object to different Entity parents... But if it works, then great :)

Comment: yes it works, i need to change the layer and this is the only way ;-)

Comment: ooo I didn't notice that one of the methods is 'detach' and the other one is 'attach', thought both were 'attach' ^^ well its ok.

Comment: @NemoPhobia What is "gap" in here: new MoveYModifier(3, getY(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()- gap);

Comment: You can always search for `MoveModifier.java` online. Fixed it.